# is there a possibility to create an editable checkbox column?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm looking for a way to show a boolean value as a clickable checkbox in the table.
In my current example, I have a value called "charged". Currently this is shown as a check. It would be great to have it as a checkbox in order to update the value really quick, instead of clicking on edit on the specific row and update it there.
[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utR5L.png)

Would appreciate any recommendations.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Backpack team has something in the works for this - a package they call "editable columns". But it will probably be launched in Feb-March 2022.

Until then, you can

(A) [create a custom column type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#creating-a-custom-column-type-1) that will make an AJAX call. For the javascript, take a look at [the delete button](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php) for inspiration.

(B) Send an email to hello@backpackforlaravel.com for beta access to that package (includes `editable_checkbox`, `editable_switch` and `editable_text` column types right now.